# How to write a full string to a file?

Tags: c, windows, string, file-io

I'm programming in Windows right now, but portable code would be welcomed too.

What I'm using right now is `fwrite(4)`, but this function needs a maximum number of elements to be written to the file. I can use `strlen(1)` here but I'd like to know if there is any better way to do this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [fputs](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fputs.html) instead:

```
FILE * f = fopen( "myfile.txt", "w" );
fputs( "Hello world\n", f );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fputs`, but using functions that require the size to be written are safer (buffer overrun).

So, IMHO, using `fwrite` would be the preferred choice.

Comment: fwrite gives you no such protection - you have to get the size with strlen(), which does effectively what fputs does

Comment: How's fwrite with strlen safer than fputs? Both will overrun the buffer if the string is missing a zero-termination.

Comment: Using fwrite with strlen gives no overrun protection, because strlen itself offers no such protection.

Comment: no function really gives this protection. but once you must pass the length you are writing, it is less likely to make BO mistakes.

Comment: @Am No you are more likely to make mistakes - for example by supplying a bad length explicitly.

Comment: @Neil, True, but it also makes you think about it. Though i cant think of an example that will expose a threat to fputs which won't do it for fwrite+strlen.

Comment: @Am: If having to do tedious manual work would make people think harder and thus avoid mistakes, we wouldn't have those thousands of security bugs due to buffer overruns.

Answer (score 0):

You might check for a null within the expected length first.