# Writing a character array to a file in C

Tags: c, pointers, file-io, char

Is this code right for writing a character array (referenced by a char pointer) to a file?

```
const char* charBuf;

FILE *outputFile = fopen("output", "a");
fprintf(outputFile, "%s\n", *charBuf);
fclose(outputFile);
```

Assume `buf` points to some character array.

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: Is it ok for us to assume you simply typed that code into your question without having ever tried to compile it (or even expecting it to compile)?

Comment: No it isn't right ... it won't compile. Did you even try?

Comment: If all you want to do is write a file, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/2216572/1181890

Comment: I'm casting it from int_u1* to char*, so I guess it's technically binary.

Comment: It does compile, but just because it compiles doesn't mean it's right. I tried it with a simple string and it seems fine, but I'm curious if that's the correct way of printing out the contents of a char* to a file.

Comment: I'm sorry for the typos in that, I'm copying it from a machine without Internet and I was in a hurry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File mode needs a quote:

```
File *outputFile = fopen("output", "a");
```

unless you have a c-string `a` defined with the mode.

Assuming you have stored some value into `charBuf`, you have to use the string in fprintf. `*charBuf` refers to the first character in that string.

```
fprintf(outputFile, "%s\n", charBuf);
```

You need to show more code for a better answer.

Comment: So `*charBuf` only refers to the first character?

Comment: @user1330642 yes, if you defined it something like: char *charBuf="..." or equivalent array.

Answer (score 0):

It's close, but you are missing a comma in `fprintf(...)`, and you use some sort of variable `charBuf` that isn't declared anywhere.

I'm guessing that you meant to write a "short complete example" for the question, and I applaud that you did as much, except that it helps to actually test your example, to focus the issues on the part you are interested in, instead of allowing lots of people point out typos and such.

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure that the file open succeeded.

```
FILE *outputFile = fopen("output", "a");
```

should be followed with an error check:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
if ( FILE == NULL )
{
   printf("ERROR: could not open output\n");
   printf("the error was: %s\n",strerror(errno));
   return;
}
```